# How To Redirect Hardware Back Button in Ionic 3?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angular, ionic-framework

I want to enable the hardware back button in ionic 3 which redirect's the page's and show's the content which we want's to redirect to the page.
as i am new to ionic 3 guide me how to redirect buttons from the hardware device?

Answer (score 2):

Something like these?

```
platform.registerBackButtonAction(()=>{
      // get the current activeNav
      let nav = app.getActiveNavs()[0];
      let active = nav.getActive();

      //crete as many difrent conditions as you need ...
      if(active.instance instanceof Pagename){
      //work u wanna do with dat page name
      }
      if(active.instance instanceof Pagename2){
      //work u wanna do with dat page name
      }

      //Go back
      nav.pop(); 

    },2)  //<- this is priority
```

You can also check if you can go back with:

```
if (nav.canGoBack()){
    nav.pop();
}
```

Comment: yes @sadsad
please,will you explain me in detail..?

Comment: can i know how to do it it's not happening..!